# How to stop my GUI from printing text indefinitely? - Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, onkeypress

I have created a GUI that will print out a list every time you press a key. Or so I thought... But instead of running the function I've made on the key press, the GUI just does it all the time.

Here's my code:

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Elements{
    static ArrayList<String> composition = new ArrayList<String>();
    static Boolean x = true;
    static JLabel gLabel = GUI();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        while(x == true){
            gLabel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("Q"), "water");
            gLabel.getActionMap().put("water", water());
            gLabel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "life");
            gLabel.getActionMap().put("life", life());
        }
    }
    public static Action water(){
        if(composition.contains("Fire")){
            composition.remove("Fire");
            composition.add("Steam");
        } else if(composition.contains("Cold")){
            composition.remove("Cold");
            composition.add("Ice");
        } else if(composition.contains("Arcane")){
            composition.remove("Arcane");
            composition.add("Poison");
        } else if(composition.contains("Lightning")){
            composition.remove("Lightning");
        } else {
            composition.add("Water");
        }
        int y = 0;
        while(y < 100){
            System.out.println("");
            y++;
        }
        System.out.println(composition);
        x = true;
        return null;
    }
    public static Action life(){
        if(composition.contains("Arcane")){
            composition.remove("Arcane");
        } else {
            composition.add("Life");
        }
        int y = 0;
        while(y < 100){
            System.out.println("");
            y++;
        }
        System.out.println(composition);
        x = true;
        return null;
    }
    private static JLabel GUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("KeyPress Handler");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("This window listens for key presses and does stuff with them. Isn't that cool?");
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return label;
    }
}
```

Instead of running `life()` and `water()` on a key press, it runs them *all the time*.

I get the output of,

`[Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life, Water, Life]`

without touching **anything**!

I have got no idea why this is happening but I think it has to do with the:
`gLabel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("Q"), "water");`

and the:

`gLabel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "life");`

If anyone could tell me what the problem is and how to fix it, that would be great.

Thanks,
Helen

P.S.: I added 2 new lines:
`gLabel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("Enter"), "stop");`
`gLabel.getActionMap().put("stop", stop());`

The function `stop()` is as follows:

`public static Action stop(){
x = false;
return null;`

As I understand it, this is meant to add a new key binding of `stop()` to `Space`.

Also, after making these changes, the output was reduced to `[Water, Life]`.

(Also, fixed the while loop)

Comment: Sorry for being slightly vague.

Comment: `while (x = true)` should be `while (x == true)` but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is that nowhere in your code, `x` has the possibility to be changed to `false`

Comment: @YassinHajaj But surely the code would still wait for a key press before running the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while ( x = true )` has to be changed to while `while ( x == true )`

and you'll have to make it possible in your code (wherever, not especially in your main since `x` is a static variable) to change the value of `x` to false.

That said, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve and I think you're going in the wrong direction.

Comment: It makes for better code in general but I still get the same output. I agree though, I am very sure I am going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

`while(x = true){` --> somehow you have to set x boolean variable false in your while condition. There is nothing else in your while loop.